# Uwp application change to Blue page. Why?

Tags: uwp, lifecycle

Why UWP application controls disappear after this step?

1. Create a simple UWP applicaiton with a button.
2. Run , Yes, I can see a button
3. Change UWP windows size to very large. I can see other application in background of UWP application. Strange, but OK, I ignore it.
4. Change the UWP application to task bar ( = Minimized )
5. Re-open it,  UWP application can not display the button again.

**Why?**

[image]

Windows 10 ver 1703, OS build 15063.447

Comment: Try running it without the debugger, do you still experience the same issue?

Comment: I run same app with "Release", but It has same problem.

Comment: Maybe worth doing a restart n even updating your video card. This is strange.

Comment: wow. I see.. My PC has 2 monitor.  ok.. When I go home, I will do test with my small laptop PC too.  thank you !

Comment: I fixed it with Video Driver update + WIndows update , Now My version change from build 15063.447 to 15063.483.   I think Windows update was effective.  thank you

Comment: Good to know! You should post an answer to this, it might help others.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it with Windows update.

My previous Version was Windows 10 ver 1703, OS build 15063.447
Current version is ver 1703, OS build 15063.483.

thank you , Justin ( again : )